# System of linear equation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

[image]

I understand that for the matrix to have a unique solution the determinant of matrix **A** must not be equal to $0$.

Hence, after finding the determinant $(12b-24),$ I found out that **b** must not be equal to $2$.

Can someone please explain the other conditions for me please? (infinitely many solutions and no solutions). I have tried solving the system by using [Gauss-Jordan elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix) but to no avail. Any advise or solution to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  If the determinant of the matrix is zero, then the matrix does not have full rank which means it is not invertible.  If the determinant is non-zero, then $A^{-1}$ exists and some $x = A^{-1}y$ is the unique solution.  Thus it admits a unique solution when $b \neq 2$, assuming you computed the determinant correctly.

On the other hand, consider the augmented matrix when $b=2$, 
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & -3 & | & a \\
4 & 2 & 0 & | & a+4 \\
-1 & -2 & 3 & | & a-1 
\end{array} \right) $$
If you did everything correctly, when you row-reduce this matrix using Gauss-Jordan elimination, you will end up with a row of all zeroes.  The corresponding vector on the right-hand side of $|$ must have a zero in that component in order for the system to be consistent.  Choosing $a$ so that this is the case will give you a system that has infinitely many solutions. You have too many variables (3) and too few equations (2).  On the other hand, every other value $a$ will mean the system has no solutions, since you will have a requirement that one equation be equal to two different constants, which can never hold.

Comment: Does this mean that the system has: 

infinitely many solutions when b = 2 and a = 1/2 

and 

no solutions when b = 2 but a ≠ 1/2

Comment: I haven't actually worked out the numbers, but it will have infinitely many solutions when $b = b^*$ and $a =  a^*$, and no solutions when $b=b^*$ and $a \neq a^*$ and have a unique solution when $b \neq b^*$.  Assuming you got $b^* = 2$ and $a^* = \frac12$ doing what I described, then yes.

Comment: This is true for this particular example, assuming you computed the determinant correctly.  It is very possible in other examples that there could be multiple $b^*$ if the determinant is non-linear in $b$.  For instance

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} b & 1 \\ 1 & b \end{array}\right)$$ is not invertible for $b = 1$ and $b = -1$.